# How to use @NamedEntityGraph with @EmbeddedId?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to have Spring Data JPA issue one query using joins to eagerly get a graph of entities:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "PositionKey.all",
    attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("positionKey.account"),
        @NamedAttributeNode("positionKey.product")
    })

@Data
public class Position {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PositionKey positionKey;        
}

@Embeddable
@Data
public class PositionKey implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId")
    private Account account;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    private Product product;
}
```

Here's my Spring Data repo:

```
public interface PositionRepository extends JpaRepository<Position, PositionKey> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "PositionKey.all", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Position> findByPositionKeyAccountIn(Set<Account> accounts);
    
}
```

This produces the following exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [positionKey.account] on this ManagedType
```

I want all of the accounts and products to be retrieved in one join statement with the positions. How can I do this / reference the embedded ID properties?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest refactoring the entity this way if it possible

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "PositionKey.all",
attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("account"),
    @NamedAttributeNode("product")
})

@Data
public class Position {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PositionKey positionKey; 

    @MapsId("accountId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId")
    private Account account;
    
    @MapsId("productId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "productId")
    private Product product;           
}

@Embeddable
@Data
public class PositionKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "accountId")
    private Long accountId;
    
    @Column(name = "productId")
    private Long productId;
}
```

Such an `EmbeddedId` is much easier to use. For instance, when you are trying to get an entity by **id**, you do not need to create a complex key containing two entities.